# Assigning a value of pointer to a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this following piece of code which is working fine:

```
int array[16][2] = {{0}};

void *buffer_ptr = NULL;

get_buffer(&buffer_ptr); // This is a function which gives me the address of 
buffer ptr

file_read(handle, size, buffer_ptr); // This function reads and stores data into buffer_ptr
```

Now I want to copy this read value into buffer_ptr into array. I am doing this currently which works:

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    array[i][0] = *((int *)buffer_ptr+(2*i));
    array[i][1] = *((int *)buffer_ptr+(2*i)+1);
}
```

But I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: what does `get_buffer` do? Your comment is not very enlightening, since you already know the address of `buffer_ptr`.

Comment: This is more of a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question

Comment: Maybe you want `memcpy(&array, buffer_ptr, sizeof array);`

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Answer (score 0):

> *But I am sure there is a better way to do this.*

Yes, read directly into the array. There's no need for the intermediate buffer.

I'm going to guess your file is a bunch of 4 byte integers and you want them two at a time. First, use a fixed width type for `array` else you might get the wrong size integer.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t array[16][2] = {{0}};
```

Then read straight from the file into the array, two 4 byte integers at time.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "rb");
if( fp == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s' for reading: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    fread(array[i], 4, 2, fp);
}
```

I believe you can even cut that down to a single read.

```
fread(array, 4, 32, fp);
```

Comment: I can't read directly. Got certain restricted regions when reading directly from memory. I give buffer_ptr a specific address which is open for reading into but array is just a local variable which will go onto stack and I can't read from external memory in it.

Comment: @R.P. You need to give more detail about what's going on in your question.